# Are there any fully conforming C++ implementations?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance

So I was trying out some features of C++0x using GCC, but I also wanted to make sure the code could be compiled with a standard C++ compiler. So I was playing around with the __cplusplus macro with ifdefs to exclude C++0x code when it wasn't asked for.

I found that the value of __cplusplus wasn't 199711L, it was 1! After a little bit of googling, I found [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros) where it says GCC isn't a fully conforming implementation.

Are there any fully conforming implementations? I know of clang, gcc, and msvc. GCC isn't a fully conforming implementation, are clang and msvc?

Comment: It's a very large standard with no known reference implementation. I doubt it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely that any compilers other than Comeau will be fully compliant in the near future due to the prohibitive complexity of implementing the export keyword.  For reasons why, see [Why We Can't Afford Export](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1426.pdf).

Comment: -1: Comeau might have far less issues then other compilers, but it's not fully compliant.

Comment: I'm selecting this one because of the informative link. Thanks.

Comment: @pgroke: +1 because there's bound to be a bug somewhere. But note that Comeau does not include a standard library, so they have also set the bar lower than others…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: not "bound to be somewhere", it's known and documented: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/4.0/docs/userman/namespace.html

Comment: @pgroke: That's a pretty old page, HTTP `last-modified` is `March 21, 1997 10:23:29 AM` and it's for 4.0 prerelease whereas the online test drive is 4.3.10, and that's from 2008. Anyway, that also reflects ongoing discussion about what the correct behavior even was, which highlights that noncompliance isn't entirely their fault.

Comment: Hm. It's the latest they got. To be honest I didn't check the date, I just assumed that if they linked to it from the home page it should be current :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) is fully conforming.  They even implemented template export.

And what's more, you can try it online, which sounds like it would help with what you're working on.

Comment: There are no bugs logged against Comeau? I bet its the most con-formant, but fully conforming?

Comment: Whenever I've had a C++ concern with my compiler and wanted to see if it was a bug, I tried it against Comeau.  I've never found it to be in wrong.

Comment: From personal experience, in quite a few cases where Comeau (EDG) disagreed with the standard, a bug was logged against the standard. Just check the Core Working Group issue list.

Comment: I wish you comeau fans would at least take the time to read their homepage... http://www.comeaucomputing.com/4.0/docs/userman/namespace.html

Comment: @pgroke: that link is for 4.0 pre-release from 1997, the last time the C++ standard was accepted!  Hardly their home page...

Comment: @Jeffrey: I said that it's *linked from* their home page. Go to http://www.comeaucomputing.com/ click on "Online Documentation" then "Namespaces". They don't seem to care about keeping their home page/online documentation current.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's possible to have a conforming compiler, but the language is *extremely* complex. There are corner-cases, ambiguities, and sometimes outright contradictions in the language that compiler writers struggle to get working.

The best way to make sure your code is standards-compliant is to brain-compile it, because you can verify things match the standard. Of course, this hinges on your ability to fully understand the standard; and whether or not any person can do that is an entirely new question. ;)

Comment: After two years I still have to ask? Please give a reason for your down-vote so I can improve the answer. If you can't give a reason, don't down-vote. Rocket science.